WebRTC: ICE connection fails when peer is outside of local network
I'm building a WebRTC proof of concept (available here) to open a data channel between two peers.
The RTC connection completes correctly (in Chrome) when both peers are in the same local network but fails when one of peers is outside the local network, despite having a TURN server in place (free tier of Metered.ca's TURN). For what I can see, the ICE connection goes into disconnected state right after having gathered the candidates.
No exceptions are raised from the WebRTC API and, debugging via chrome://webrtc-internals, it seems that the ICE candidates are correctly gathered (host, relay and srflx). Any clue on what might be causing the ICE disconnection? How can I proceed about diagnosing the issue?
Activity from joiner peer (both peers in local network)
icegatheringstatechange - gathering
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:3284536843 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.93 57916 typ host generation 0 ufrag V6vO network-id 2 network-cost 10
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:697908812 1 udp 2122194687 10.16.97.58 44994 typ host generation 0 ufrag V6vO network-id 1 network-cost 900
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1821175605 1 udp 1686052607 W.X.Y.Z 57916 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.93 rport 57916 generation 0 ufrag V6vO network-id 2 network-cost 10
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1030544031 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.93 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag V6vO network-id 2 network-cost 10
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:3610503896 1 tcp 1518214911 10.16.97.58 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag V6vO network-id 1 network-cost 900
iceconnectionstatechange - checking
connectionstatechange - connecting
icecandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:3216401071 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.108 53490 typ host generation 0 ufrag M1bA network-id 1 network-cost 10
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1890613798 1 udp 25108479 64.227.76.184 63448 typ relay raddr W.X.Y.Z rport 51800 generation 0 ufrag V6vO network-id 2 network-cost 10
icecandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:2121807333 1 udp 1686052607 W.X.Y.Z 53490 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.108 rport 53490 generation 0 ufrag M1bA network-id 1 network-cost 10, url: stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
icecandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1092400699 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.108 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag M1bA network-id 1 network-cost 10
iceconnectionstatechange - connected
icegatheringstatechange - complete

Activity from joiner peer (starter peer outside local network)
icegatheringstatechange - gathering
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:90538786 1 udp 2122260223 10.16.97.58 44230 typ host generation 0 ufrag NW/0 network-id 1 network-cost 900
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:4224669622 1 tcp 1518280447 10.16.97.58 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag NW/0 network-id 1 network-cost 900
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1168109963 1 udp 1686052607 31.221.168.175 16430 typ srflx raddr 10.16.97.58 rport 44230 generation 0 ufrag NW/0 network-id 1 network-cost 900
addIceCandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:3471918397 1 udp 25108479 165.227.233.194 45331 typ relay raddr 31.221.168.175 rport 16406 generation 0 ufrag NW/0 network-id 1 network-cost 900
iceconnectionstatechange - checking
connectionstatechange - connecting
icecandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:2110517235 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.108 51199 typ host generation 0 ufrag wYBP network-id 1 network-cost 10
icecandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1026661722 1 udp 1686052607 W.X.Y.Z 51199 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.108 rport 51199 generation 0 ufrag wYBP network-id 1 network-cost 10, url: stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
icecandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:55954174 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.108 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag wYBP network-id 1 network-cost 10
icecandidate - sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:210099374 1 udp 25108479 64.227.76.184 48031 typ relay raddr W.X.Y.Z rport 51444 generation 0 ufrag wYBP network-id 1 network-cost 10, relayProtocol: tcp, url: turn:global.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp
icegatheringstatechange - complete
iceconnectionstatechange - disconnected

Finally, a bit of context about the app in case it helps:

Peer A starts the connection and sends a URL (which includes the session description and candidates) to Peer B. The signaling server is up to the user (e.g. Discord, Email, Telegram, etc.)
Peer B opens the URL (the session description and candidates are autopopulated in the text area) and joins the connection. Peer B then sends its session description to Peer A using the same signaling server.
Peer A enters the session description from Peer B and completes the connection.


Have you checked the connection to the TURN server isnt blocked behind a hostile NAT/firewall ?

@StefanVučković I certainly have not. How do I go about that? WireShark?

Yeah you can try with that method, you can also try use whatsmyip, and compare against what your computer thinks your ip is.
I think if your on chrome you can also view chrome://webrtc-internals and look at the logs to see the ICE candidate gathering etc.
It could potentially be worth having a STUN fallback if TURN doesn't work.
I googled for NAT testing and NAT-PMP and UPnP are the top ones I saw

Check Previous Discussion as well

Thanks for the other post  The public IPs in the canidates are correct, the logs I attached come from chrome://webrtc-internals, and I do provide a STUN server as well (if I understand it correctly, that's the responsible for the srflx ICE candidate). I can check the NAT/firewall settings on my machine but the users of the app will not be able to diagnose this sort of problem. Are we facing a hard limitation of WebRTC then?

Yeah essentially, any peer to peer connection will always suffer from restrictive NATs, just depends how hard.
I mean the whole concept of a NAT sucks overall for P2P communication, however became necessary due to the lack of IPv4 addresses.
All we can do as developers is to provide as many backups as possible essentially, but if the user is unable to form that connection its out of out control

Issue can be related to application (peer handling), signaling or TURN server.
Rather than reinventing the wheel you can replicate a setup that works and you can test prior to deploying.
In example, you can confirm this P2P WebRTC Videocall demo works for your scenario. Then you can use a similar setup with Coturn, the WebRTC Signaling Server with STUN/TURN support from GitHub and test the WebRTC Videocall application on own setup. Then build your own app logic using similar signaling.

Thanks for the suggestion, @TopReseller. The videowhisper demo works when the WebTC clients are in different networks  I've open an issue in their demo repository requesting for the client side source code (only the bundled assets are committed). Hopefully I can find the missing bit comparing my code to theirs.
